# Passing select row of HTML table to next JSP page

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, jstl, el

I created a `HTML` data table in a page say `DATABROWSER.JSP` through Java script (including all its row and there on click function in `JS`). I want to pass the selected(*highlighted*) row value to *another JSP* page(a new page that i open after selecting) **without submiting** the first page. !!

Comment: since you're using javascript for most of what you're doing why not just use js to call a servlet and have the servlet redirect to the page you're wanting? Then you're not really submitting the page, per say.

Comment: You can do it through ajax. Post your jsp code. The form won't be submitted but would call the action using javascript

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to get to another JSP without going back to the server.

I would place the items you select in hidden form fields and then submit the form. This would allow you to bring back a new JSP.

Comment: okay can u tell me the best suited way u have in mind ?? thanx in advance